# правило для "то же самое(,) такая же"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Правило постановки запятой в предложении:

"Здесь, по существу, то же **самое,** **такая** же путаница и мешанина в фабуле фильма, так же налицо безыдейное объединение, с одной стороны, натурализма и бытовщины, а с другой, - сверхъестественных, чуть ли не каббалистических происшествий и пертурбаций, происходящих с холеными супергероями, которые элегантно и триумфально, не потерявши ни волоска, запросто преодолевают нагромождение хитроумных лабиринтов и запутанных интриг, чем сеют в душе доверчивых зрителей иллюзии чересчур сладкой жизни, сверхэффектных приключений и легкодостижимых опереточных побед."

к сожалению, ничего не могу найти у Розенталя :(

---

это может быть параллельной конструкцией?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предположить, что это **сложное предложение нестандартной структуры**, поэтому нечто подобное трудно найти у Розенталя.

(1) **Здесь**, по существу, **то же самое**, (2) (**здесь**) такая же **путаница и мешанина** в фабуле фильма, (3) (**здесь**) так же налицо безыдейное **объединение**...

Запятые ставятся между простыми предложениями с бессоюзной связью, при этом  предложение (3) является главным в СПП с последовательным подчинением придаточных.

Эти простые предложения имеют эллиптический характер и строятся по схеме "обстоятельство (здесь) - подлежащее".

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я полностью с Вами согласна.

Answer (score 2):

> Здесь, по существу, **то же самое**, такая же путаница и мешанина в
>   фабуле фильма, так же налицо безыдейное объединение...

По-моему, вместо запятой после ***то же самое*** лучше поставить двоеточие.

[ПРАВИЛО](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113):

> **§ 33.** Если обобщающее слово предшествует ряду однородных членов, то после обобщающего слова ставится двоеточие...

Comment: Возможно, но это исходный текст по Н.Д. Голеву. И у него запятая.

Comment: Ну и что с того, что у Голева запятая? Вполне возможно, что если бы Голев **повнимательнее** перечитал свою статью (http://lingvo.asu.ru/golev/articles/v93.html), он бы и в слове **орфография** (см.: Часть I. Методические принципы курса "**орфография** и лингвистическая культура") заменил бы строчную **"о"** на прописную (тем более, что строчкой ниже он это сделал). И в этом предложении -- 

_"Может быть, и вы замечали такую странность: не знаешь, как правильно, **заминка: Думаешь**, думаешь, **наконец, пишешь**…"_

-- вместо двоеточия после слова **заминка** поставил бы многоточие. Да и…

Comment: Не согласен я с Голевым и здесь:

_"…объединение, с одной стороны, натурализма и бытовщины, **а с другой, - сверхъестественных**, чуть ли не каббалистических происшествий и пертурбаций"._ После "а с другой", по-моему, вполне достаточно одного **тире**.  У Голева же -- **запятая и тире**. Зачем?

Comment: Вероятно, материал на данной странице просто неграмотно перенесен из бумажного источника, поскольку глупые ошибки там встречаются повсеместно. Ко мне этот текст попал через моего преподавателя - кандидата филологических наук. Я сама не филолог, на Ваши вопросы ответить не могу.